# Show that $\int_a^b xdx = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$ using upper and lower Riemann sums

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's my work so far:

Let $f(x) = x$ and suppose that $P = \{x_0, x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$ is the partition for interval $[a,b]$, creating $n$ number of subintervals with equal lengths.

$L_f(P)$ denotes the lower Riemann sum associated with partition P and $U_f(P)$ denotes the upper Riemann sum associated with partition P. So from what I know, $U_f(P)$ will always be greater than or equal to the true definite integral. Likewise, $L_f(P)$ will always be less than or equal to the true definite integral. Like so...

$$L_f(P) \leq \int_a^b xdx \leq U_f(P)$$

To calculate $L_f(P)$, for each integer $i$ in $[1,n]$, let $m_i = \textrm{min}\{f(x) \,|\, x \  \textrm{in} \ [x_{i-1}, x_i]\}$. Then...

\begin{align}
L_f(P) &= \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i - x_{i-1}) = (\frac{b-a}{n})(a+ ...+m_{n})
\end{align}

how can I continue? My goal is to show the upper and lower sums are equal.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}?$

Comment: Yeah, it is. Sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to being done. Note that $x_i = a + \frac{i}{n}(b-a)$, so
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+ \frac{i}{n}(b-a)) \\
&= na + \frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i \\
&= na + \frac{b-a}{n}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
\end{align*}
The lower Riemann sum then becomes
\begin{align*}
L_f(P)=\frac{b-a}{n}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^nm_i &= a(b-a) + \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}
\end{align*}
A very similar computation gives us that
$$U_f(P) = a(b-a)+\frac{n+1}{n} \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}.$$
Letting $n$ approach $\infty$ we can see that we get the same limit namely
\begin{align*}
a(b-a) + \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} &= \frac{2ab - 2a^2 + b^2 + a^2 - 2ab}{2} = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: You should state that for a sequence of partitions $P_{n}$ such that $||P_{n}||\to 0$. We have $L_{f}(P_{n})\xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \int_{\bar{a}}^{b} f$ and similarly for the upper sum

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron  No this is not necessary to state. Also the implication you stated only holds when $f$ is Riemann integrable, but if the purpose of the exercise is to show directly by definition, that the function $x\mapsto x$ is Riemann integrable, then we cannot assume this beforehand. My calculation specifically shows, that
$$a(b-a) + \frac{n-1}{n} \frac{(b-a)^2}{2} \leq \int_a^b x \: dx \leq a(b-a) + \frac{n+1}{n}\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. And as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get the inequality
$$\frac{b^2-a^2}{2} \leq \int_a^b x \: dx \leq \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. Your hint about $x_i = a + \frac{i}{n}(b-a) $ did it all for me. Couldn’t come up with that for some reason.